# java gui and logic

Tags: java, user-interface, logic

it s 3 hours i m tring to understand a thing  but no  success...

the problem is:

i have a class Gui( a client) with a main   for a cardgame. the Gui has a main that has in an invokelater a Runnable where the logic ( a separate class managing the gamesession) runs and some methods to manipulate the order of the cards.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                PokerClientGui gui = new PokerClientGui();
                gui.setVisible(true);
                PokerClient pokerClient = new PokerClient(gui);

                pokerClient.gameSession();
            }
        });
}
```

The logic is created in the main of the Gui passing the Gui itself to the logic.
As  far as i am proceding in the program there are no problems since all the objects/strings sent from the server to the client logic are received  and for example the Hand is passed to the gui and displayed correctly.
The problem comes now: i want to pass from the gui to the logic, the manipulated  hand to send it  to the sever via method of the logic class.
Since this function is called by the event mouse on the Gui (and not in the main of the Gui)   i have no handle to the logic object so i can t use its  sending objects method.
 I tried changing to static the method of the logic that sends  and i made statics also the member involved in sending  things on the socket.....

it doesn t  send anything ..... it s not a problem of something wrong and i try to catch the exceptions (and nothing comes from them)

where m i wrong? what i am missing ? how should i bind the gui and the logic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you could create an event queue in your `Runnable()` class, and pass it to both your gui and your client constructors.

The client would add events for the GUI to display, and the GUI would add events for the client to process. It might be easier with two queues, one for each direction, rather than re-using a single channel for both directions.

Then your GUI and your client would add the event queue from this object into the list of things to 'check' when waiting in their event loops. When an event comes from the other object, it wakes the current object to do processing, same as events from the server or the user.

Comment: i think i could us one event queue since i can communicate from the logic to the gui with no problems.......but i get lost ( beginner) on how  to do this ... i understand in general the concept and through this i could wake up the  loop in the logic.... but do u mean to create anotehr runnable with java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() ??? ..... (i am looking online for more information but no success untill now)

Comment: @user595983, I'm thinking something far simpler: [java.util.Queue](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/queue.html)

Comment: oh -__- i make always things too complicated.... so just an object in a form of queue where the gui and logic parts of the client can read and write on ..... thx!!

Answer (score 1):

In place of creating the object of PokerClientGui in main class u better create its object directly in the PokerClient object and access its object gameSession() .

Comment: hmmm  but that doens t change  the  problem...i still need to communicate from the gui to the logic and the logic object is not seen by the Gui.  It s like passing, as i did, the gui to the logic

Comment: u are right too.... and then i can create the gui passing the logic to it ( so i can invoke  method of the logic directly in the gui)